# What changed in the SPARQL code for this parliamentary term?

Tags: text, sparql, data-analysis, missing-data

I have been successfully retrieving data from the following Open-Link Dataset: http://linkedpolitics.ops.few.vu.nl/web/html/home.html
for the 5th, 6th and 7th parliamentary term of the EP which I am then cleaning in STATA.

However, the coding seems to differ for the 8th term because I get a lot less speeches when I use the lpv:translatedText function that I have used before. I can't help but think that a LOT more should come up in the timeframe I am specifying than what the SPARQL endpoint returns. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code I used for National parties (here with the dates for anything after the 7th term):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?countryname ?birth ?gender ?partyname ?start ?end ?date ?speechnr ?parlterm ?dictionary  
WHERE {
  ?speech lpv:translatedText ?text.
  ?speech dcterms:date ?date.
    ?speech lpv:docno ?speechnr.
  ?speech lpv:speaker ?speaker.
  ?speaker lpv:name ?name.
  ?speaker lpv:dateOfBirth ?birth.
  ?speaker lpv:gender ?gender.
  ?speaker lpv:politicalFunction ?function. 
?function lpv:institution ?party.
?party rdf:type lpv:NationalParty.
  ?party rdfs:label ?partyname.
  ?function lpv:beginning ?start.
  ?function lpv:end ?end.
  ?speaker lpv:countryOfRepresentation ?country. 
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryname.
  BIND("8" as ?parlterm)
  BIND("representation" as ?dictionary) 
FILTER ( ?date > "2014-07-01"^^xsd:date )  
 FILTER(langMatches(lang(?text), "en"))
FILTER(CONTAINS(?text, 'female representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women’s representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'equal representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'gender representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women in science') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women in business') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women’s leadership'))       
} ORDER BY ?date ?speechnr
```

and here is the code I used for the FEMM committee (again anything after 7th parliamentary term):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?countryname ?birth ?gender ?start_com ?end_com ?date ?speechnr ?parlterm ?dictionary ?FEMM  
WHERE {
 ?speech lpv:translatedText ?text.
  ?speech dcterms:date ?date.
 ?speech lpv:docno ?speechnr.
  ?speech lpv:speaker ?speaker. 
 ?speaker lpv:name ?name.
 ?speaker lpv:dateOfBirth ?birth.
  ?speaker lpv:gender ?gender.
  ?speaker lpv:politicalFunction ?function. 
 ?function lpv:institution ?institution.
  ?institution rdfs:label ?committee. 
FILTER CONTAINS (?committee, "Committee on Women's Rights and Gender Equality")
 BIND("Yes" as ?FEMM).
  ?function lpv:beginning ?start_com.
  ?function lpv:end ?end_com.
 ?speaker lpv:countryOfRepresentation ?country. 
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryname.
 BIND("8" as ?parlterm)
  BIND("representation" as ?dictionary) 
FILTER ( ?date > "2014-07-01"^^xsd:date )  
 FILTER(langMatches(lang(?text), "en"))
FILTER(CONTAINS(?text, 'female representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women’s representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'equal representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'gender representation') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women in science') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women in business') ||  CONTAINS(?text, 'women’s leadership'))   
} ORDER BY ?date ?speechnr
```

Thank you.

Comment: *" I can't help but think that a LOT more should come up in the timeframe I am specifying than what the SPARQL endpoint returns. "* - how do you know this? I mean, you can download the whole dataset and check the raw RDF data. I'm pretty sure the RDF schema is fixed, so I don't understand what you mean by "changed"

Comment: If you omit the filter with the `contains` from the first query it returns results. So there is maybe no such data matching the terms because the rest of the query of course works and returns results. There are 655 entries matching the rest of the query, can can query all those speech texts, download it and then do a quick search to see if there is any text matching your terms. If yes, it's a bug. If not, there is literally no such data

Comment: Just check the `text`bindings - the text seems to be not in English language although the language  tags are `"en"` - this means, there was some issue during data creation, which means you filter doesn't work with English search terms. That means, you're lost, can't do anything as the data has just been wrongly translated

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. I think a lot more should come up because I know how much came up for a year in each other term and that was sometimes more than 2,000 entries, so 655 for that whole time is just very little and can't be right. I also noticed the English language issue which is why I tried translated, rather than spoken Text but your last comment seems to hit the nail on the head. Thanks.